# Using ske.min.js in Meteor js project

Tags: javascript, templates, meteor, meteor-blaze, skel

I have been trying to use the `skel.min.js` library in my app but keep getting `ReferenceError: skel is not defined`. This is my setup:

```
<body>
    {{>HomeLayout}}
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/skel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/util.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
</body>
<template name="Home">
    
</template>
```

and this is where the error is flagged:

```
skel.breakpoints({
        xlarge: '(max-width: 1680px)',
        large: '(max-width: 1280px)',
        medium: '(max-width: 980px)',
        small: '(max-width: 736px)',
        xsmall: '(max-width: 480px)',
        'xlarge-to-max': '(min-width: 1681px)',
        'small-to-xlarge': '(min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 1680px)'
    });
```

Other libraries are loaded but I think it is the only one not loaded. Is a workaround available?

Comment: Try to import the js in the file that you are using, something like `import * as skel from "/path/to/skel.min.js" `

Comment: Does import work on the client? I only have client codes now, or where should I put it?